# C# moving a datetimepicker from a winform to another

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datetimepicker

I made a program that use a dataset and it makes 3 reports, 
the things is it sets from 2 datetimepicker (start and end of the period)

but they are in a FORM and I separated each report by a button
so each report appear in a different window.
and the window loads, but I don't know how I can pass the datetimepickers, from the first FORM to the other 3 FORMS (each window with a different report)

```
     public partial class GenerarIndicadores : Form
{
    unyrepDataSetTableAdapters.cargadatosTableAdapter ta_cargadatos;
    public GenerarIndicadores()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ta_cargadatos = new unyrepDataSetTableAdapters.cargadatosTableAdapter();
        int total = ta_cargadatos.GetData().Count;
        dateTimePicker1.MinDate = ta_cargadatos.GetData()[0].fechaInicio;
        dateTimePicker2.MinDate = ta_cargadatos.GetData()[0].fechaInicio;
        dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = ta_cargadatos.GetData()[total - 1].fechaTermino;
        dateTimePicker2.MaxDate = ta_cargadatos.GetData()[total - 1].fechaTermino;
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new GenerarIndicadorGrupo().ShowDialog();
        this.aux_view5TableAdapter.FillTest(this.unyrepDataSet.aux_view5, dateTimePicker1.Value, dateTimePicker2.Value);

    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new GenerarIndicadorProveedor().ShowDialog();
        this.aux_view5TableAdapter.FillTest(this.unyrepDataSet.aux_view5, dateTimePicker1.Value, dateTimePicker2.Value);

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new GenerarIndicadorObras().ShowDialog();
        this.aux_view5TableAdapter.FillTest(this.unyrepDataSet.aux_view5, dateTimePicker1.Value, dateTimePicker2.Value);

    }
```

I don't know how I can pass the dateTimePickers to the others winforms so the reports can get the info perfectly.

Comment: Expose the timeframe as public properties of your child windows. When the form closes, before disposal, save off those ranges to your main form. Then, populate them before calling ShowDialog on your next window.

Comment: I didn't get the "Expose the timeframe as public properties of your child windows" how can I do that? and
how can I save those ranges??

Answer (score 0):

Store the value of the DateTimePicker in a property then get it through the other forms.

form1:

```
    public string dTime{get;set;}
    dTime = datetimepicker1.Value.Date;
```

form2:

```
public string getDTime{get;set;}
getDtime = form1.dTime;
datetimepicker2.value.Date = getDtime;
```

P.S.
make sure you initialize form1 to other forms for you to get the value of dTime.